# Tensorflow: Compute Precision, Recall, F1 Score

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

i built a BERT Model (Bert-base-multilingual-cased) from Huggingface and want to evaluate the Model with its Precision, Recall and F1-score next to accuracy, as accurays isn't always the best metrics for evaluation.

[Here](https://github.com/peterbayerle/huggingface_notebook/blob/main/distilbert_tf.ipynb) is the example notebook which I have modified for my use case.

Create Train/Test Data:

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer, TFBertModel, TFBertForSequenceClassification

TEST_SPLIT = 0.1
BATCH_SIZE = 2

train_size = int(len(x) * (1-TEST_SPLIT))

tfdataset = tfdataset.shuffle(len(x))
tfdataset_train = tfdataset.take(train_size)
tfdataset_test = tfdataset.skip(train_size)

tfdataset_train = tfdataset_train.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
tfdataset_test = tfdataset_test.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

Build Model:

```
MODEL_NAME = 'bert-base-multilingual-cased'
N_EPOCHS = 2

model = TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)
optimizer = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=3e-5)
loss = losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(tfdataset_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=N_EPOCHS)
```

Example Output:

```
All model checkpoint layers were used when initializing TFBertForSequenceClassification.

Some layers of TFBertForSequenceClassification were not initialized from the model checkpoint at bert-base-multilingual-cased and are newly initialized: ['classifier']
You should probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference.
Epoch 1/2
415/415 [==============================] - 741s 2s/step - loss: 0.6652 - accuracy: 0.6321
Epoch 2/2
415/415 [==============================] - 717s 2s/step - loss: 0.6619 - accuracy: 0.6429
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fc970d72750>
```

Evaluate:

```
benchmarks = model.evaluate(tfdataset_test, return_dict=True, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
print(benchmarks)
```

Example Output:

```
93/93 [==============================] - 42s 404ms/step - loss: 0.6536 - accuracy: 0.6108
{'loss': 0.6535539627075195, 'accuracy': 0.6108108162879944}
```

With this, I just get the accuracy score. But at the and I want to have a classification report with all the mentioned metrics.

Does anybody know how to do this with such "tfdatasets"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: since your using the keras api you can just add in the metrics sections of your code take a look here: https://keras.io/api/metrics/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `tensorflow-addons` in addition to metrics that belong in `tf` main/base package.

```
       #pip install tensorflow-addons
       import tensorflow as tf
       import tensorflow_addons as tfa

       ....

       model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.00001),
                     loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                     metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(),
                              tf.keras.metrics.Precision(),
                              tf.keras.metrics.Recall(),
                              tfa.metrics.F1Score(num_classes=nb_classes,
                                                  average='macro',
                                                  threshold=0.5))
```

Comment: When changing it to this I get following error message: "ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 2) are incompatible". Do you maybe know a reason for this?

Comment: Because you may be performing binary classification instead oc categorical classification.

Comment: Now it prints out this error message: "ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 2) vs (None, 1))". So I think I have to figure out how to reshape my tfdataset

Answer (score 1):

This works for me know (found [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/45165/how-to-get-accuracy-f1-precision-and-recall-for-a-keras-model)):

```
from keras import backend as K

def recall_m(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    possible_positives = 
    K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
    recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + 
    K.epsilon())
    return recall

def precision_m(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    predicted_positives = 
    K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
    return precision

def f1_m(y_true, y_pred):
    precision = precision_m(y_true, y_pred)
    recall = recall_m(y_true, y_pred)
    return 2*((precision*recall)/(precision+recall+K.epsilon()))

# compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc',f1_m,precision_m, recall_m])
```